# javascript function return different result than expected

Tags: javascript

In this website

https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

I use this javascript function to know the position of the country in the table

```
{
    function findMatchingRow(word) {
        const found = []
        const trList = document.querySelectorAll('#main_table_countries_today > tbody > tr')
        trList.forEach((tr, i) => {
            if (tr.textContent.match(word)) {
                found.push({
                    index: i,
                    content: tr.textContent
                })
            }
        });
        return found
    }
    const matches = findMatchingRow("Australia")
    console.log(matches)

    if (matches.length > 0) {
        console.log('found at:', matches.map(m => m.index))
    }
}
```

For only Australia, it returns 8 instead of 35

for other countries like poland it gives correct number,

I still can't figure it out

**Any help will be appreciated !**

Comment: When you say it returns 8 instead of 36, what do you mean? Why should it return 36?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML as well!

Comment: @WillD Hemeans `matches.length` is only 8 instead of 36.

Comment: You're only counting rows. If a row has `Australia` multiple times, it will only be returned once.

Comment: sorry it's 35 not 36

Comment: @WillD Why it shouldn't ?

Comment: @FZs i posted the link of the website at the beginning

Comment: @Barmar it will be no duplicate country names

Comment: @JDEVv I see, but here's why I asked for HTML and not a link: 1. The HTML page is much bigger than the part relevant to this issue, so it's harder to find that part, and other issues may appear; 2. Linked sites may change or go offline over time, so a future visitor might won't be able to reproduce the issue; 3. Websites are harder to debug (need of Developer Tools, etc.). Links are good, *if they're accompanied by relevant code*. Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to get text content from the entire row, You can just match first `td` content. There are places like Australia in anywhere in `tr`. So narrow down the search.

```
function findMatchingRow(word) {
  const trList = [...document.querySelectorAll(
    "#main_table_countries_today > tbody > tr"
  )];
  let found;
  trList.some((tr, i) => {
    const name = tr.children[0].textContent.trim();
    if (name.includes(word)) {
      found = {
        index: i,
        content: tr.textContent,
      };
    }
    return found;
  });
  return found;
}
const found = findMatchingRow("Australia");

if (found) {
  console.log("found at:"+ JSON.stringify(found));
  console.log("found at:"+ found.index);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem was and how you solved it? Adding `.trim()` won't help this. If a trimmed string contains a match, so will the untrimmed string.

Comment: i added details. That is I normally follow for any TD, you can also direct match. No space.

Comment: How will narrowing the search make it return *more* results?

Comment: There is only one Australia in the country list. And the solution should be optimized. I have added detail. what was the issue? He/She can find a better solution. based on his requirements.

Comment: They're expecting to get 36 matches in the array, but they only get 8 matches. How will narrowing the search get all 36 matches?

Comment: can u read console.. they are looking for index not the match of the count

Comment: They're talking about `console.log(matches)` It only has 8 elements, not 36.

Comment: that is log.. and there is not 36 Australia in that table for ur information. `console.log('found at:', matches.map(m => m.index))`

Comment: Did you actually try their code? `matches.length` is `8` that's what they're talking about.

Comment: He is looking for index of the Australia, `console.log('found at:', matches.map(m => m.index))`

Comment: He cant find the correct approach, so he fectch all the data matching and try to figure it out the solution out of it. But he is implementing search feature. Like for particular country, how many cases are there?

Comment: @Barmar Did it clarify your concern ??

Comment: How can i get that index as an output ? not that kind of array

Comment: The output will be : "found at:" `{ index: 35
content: "↵Australia↵6,303↵↵59 ↵+3↵3,265↵2,979↵80↵247↵2↵351,380↵13,780↵Australia/Oceania↵"}`

Comment: @xdeepakv it shows `found at: [object Object]
` instead of `found at: 35
`
i'm using it in android app

Comment: @xdeepakv so i think the output is the 1st object, how can i do it ? really appreciate your help

Comment: use `,` not `+`, else use JSON.stringify(found), I have updated solution

Answer (score 0):

you only search in text-Content of the whole tr (row). text-Content are all nodes. Australia results in an Array, cause many entries have "Australia/Oceania" as data-continent attr.

Comment: Oh ok, i think i understand now, so how can i seleect a specific row ?